# Click action on part of the string in UILabel other than NSUrl in Swift

Tags: swift

I tried to make action when tap on particular string in uilabel. In the below example I tried to make on "Terms and Conditions" and "Privacy Policy." in the entire string *"By clicking on Register, you hereby agree to our \nTerms and Conditions and Privacy Policy."*. 
But I achieved partly that means "Terms and Conditi" and "Privacy ". I have given the range but still not working for the given range. The reason may be when I am giving the range, I am using NSString instead of NSAttributed string. If I am correct how should I rewrite the code to work properly.

```
func labelTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let ts = NSTextStorage(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string:mylabel.text!))
    let lm = NSLayoutManager()
    ts.addLayoutManager(lm)
    let tc = NSTextContainer(size: CGSizeMake(mylabel.frame.size.width,mylabel.frame.size.height))
    lm.addTextContainer(tc) // ****
    tc.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    let toRange1 = (mylabel.text! as NSString).rangeOfString("Privacy Policy.")
    let toRange2 = (mylabel.text! as NSString).rangeOfString("Terms and Conditions")
    let gr1 = lm.glyphRangeForCharacterRange(toRange1, actualCharacterRange: nil) // ****
    let gr2 = lm.glyphRangeForCharacterRange(toRange2, actualCharacterRange: nil)

    let glyphRect1 = lm.boundingRectForGlyphRange(gr1, inTextContainer: tc)
    let glyphRect2 = lm.boundingRectForGlyphRange(gr2, inTextContainer: tc)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a UIButton?

Comment: If we are using button for part of the text, you will face problem when screen size differs or static text is changed(if client requires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I have done the mistaken @

> let ts = NSTextStorage(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string:mylabel.text!))

It should be written as

> let ts = NSTextStorage(attributedString: mylabel.attributedText!)

For accuracy use self.view.layoutIfNeeded() at the first line of labelTapped() method